Problem involving length of the arc of the curves
How can we show that the length of the arc of the curves $x^2=a^2(1-e^{y/a})$ at any arbitary point $(x,y)$ is equal to $alog(\frac{a+x}{a-x})-x$ ?
Basically I know the formula for finding the arc length of cartesian curves. I computed $x$ in terms of $y$ as $x=a\sqrt{1-e^{y/a}}$
Also $\frac{dx}{dy}=\frac{-e^{y/a}}{2\sqrt{1-e^{y/a}}}$
thus I tried integrating with the formula $Arc Length=\int_0^y\sqrt{1+(\frac{dx}{dy})^2}dy$
on simplifying further I got
$Arc = \frac{1}{2}\int_0^y\frac{2-e^{y/a}}{\sqrt{1-e^{y/a}}}dy$
But I am having problem simplifying it further so Please assist me!

Hint Let first $\sqrt{1-e^{\frac{y}{a}}}=t$

Well sire @Claude Leibovici , Someone gave the solution already but as you hinted, I tried and I solved it this way too! So thanks .

I would do it the usual way not to include a complicated integral. If one were to express the $y$ in terms of $x$, not other way around, it would lead to:

$y(x) = a \ln{\left(1-\dfrac{x^2}{a^2}\right)}$
the arclength integral:
$$
l 
= \int_{0}^{x} \sqrt{1 + {\left(\dfrac{\mathbb{d}y}{\mathbb{d}x}\right)}^2} \,\mathbb{d}x
= \int_{0}^{x} \sqrt{1 + {\left(\dfrac{2ax}{a^2-x^2}\right)}^2} \,\mathbb{d}x
= \int_{0}^{x} \sqrt{\left(\dfrac{a^2+x^2}{a^2-x^2}\right)^2} \,\mathbb{d}x 
= \int_{0}^{x} \frac{a^2+x^2}{a^2-x^2} \mathbb{d}x 
$$

This integral could be easily solved by rational fraction decomposition:
$$
l 
= \int_{0}^{x} \frac{a^2+x^2}{a^2-x^2} \mathbb{d}x 
= \int_{0}^{x} 1 + \frac{2x^2}{(a-x)(a+x)} \mathbb{d}x 
= \int_{0}^{x} \left(1 + \frac{a}{a-x} + \frac{a}{a+x} -2 \right)\mathbb{d}x 
$$
From here it easily follows:
$$
l 
= \int_{0}^{x} \left(-1 + \frac{a}{a-x} + \frac{a}{a+x} \right)\mathbb{d}x
= -x + a\ln(a+x) - a\ln(a-x) = a\ln{\left( \dfrac{a+x}{a-x}\right)} - x
$$

Yes Sire! Thanks. I guess I was just giving myself a hard time .
